# jquery tooltip on php

Tags: php, jquery, css, tooltip

I have 6 buttons(with tooltips) that are generated through PHP and they are all disabled except for the first button. The disabled buttons will only be enabled based on the record on the database. 
By the way, I used jquery tooltip http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/
I enabled the tooltip for all elements with the title attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').tooltip({
        showBody: " - ",
    });

});
</script>
```

It worked fine when the page first loads or when the page is refresh.
Now I have a function that check if the buttons status are changed from disabled to enabled. After that I fetch the result and put in a variable $buttons then print it on the div that holds the current buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("menus").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($buttons, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);  ?>;
</script>
```

The problem is that the tooltip reverts back to the default tooltip. 
I'm not sure if it's in the css or the javascript since I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding content AFTER you've called the .tooltip(...) stuff.

try calling .tooltip on the content you add into the .innerHtml AFTER you've made the call to get the new content.

Comment: I've tried to put this  $('*').tooltip({ showBody: " - " }); after the inner html and it worked but the other tooltip that is not changed is now not working...